# Consider the sample space of $2$ die. If $(1,2)$ does not mean the same as $(2,1)$, why is there not two sets of $(1,1)$.. etc?

Tags: probability, statistics

$(1,2)$ does not equal $(2,1)$

So why does the sample space not include $(1,1)$ twice?

Answer (score 1):

In order to get $(1,1)$, the first die must be $1$ and the second die must be $1$. So there is only one possibility. If one die is $1$ and the other die is $2$, then there are two ways this can happen: either the first die is $1$ or the second die is $1$.